# docker-compose for ansible gui polemarch

Tags: docker-compose

I see the docker-compose wiki POLEMARCH (ansible gui) and a bunch of examples at this URL https://gitlab.com/vstconsulting/polemarch-docker/wikis/home but I don't see a full working copy with all the parameters

It expects the MySQL to be already installed but I want to run MySQL and RabbitMQ inside the same docker-compose stack

Can anyone help me with the actual docker-compose file including RabbitMQ, MySQL/MariaDB etc?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use within portainer.io to run PoleMarch, just add it into a docker compose file.

```
# https://polemarch.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html
version: '2'
services:
  polemarch:
    image: vstconsulting/polemarch
    restart: always
    environment:    
      POLEMARCH_DB_TYPE: mysql
      POLEMARCH_DB_NAME: project-db
      POLEMARCH_DB_USER: project-user
      POLEMARCH_DB_PASSWORD: project-pas
      POLEMARCH_DB_PORT: 3306
      POLEMARCH_DB_HOST: polemarch_mysql
      DB_INIT_CMD: "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', default_storage_engine=INNODB, NAMES 'utf8', CHARACTER SET 'utf8', SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_unicode_ci'"
      CACHE_LOCATION: 'redis://polemarch_redis:6379/0'
      RPC_ENGINE: 'redis://polemarch_redis:6379/1'
      RPC_CONCURRENCY: 15
      POLEMARCH_LOG_LEVEL: DEBUG
      POLEMARCH_DEBUG: 'true'
      TIMEZONE: 'Asia/Vladivostok'
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /opt/polemarch/projects:/projects 
      - /opt/polemarch/hooks:/hooks 
    depends_on:
      - polemarch_mysql
      - polemarch_redis

  polemarch_redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    expose:
      - "6379"      

  polemarch_mysql:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: project-user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: project-pas
      MYSQL_DATABASE: project-db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: project-root
    volumes:
      - /opt/polemarch/db:/var/lib/mysql
    expose:
      - "3306"
```

Once the service is up and running you can connect with the user:password admin:admin